# Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active

Tags: flutter, dart

I have built an app that sends the live location(latitude and longitude) of a user every 5 seconds upon clicking on a button. However, when I switch to another screen using the Bottom Navigation Bar, I get a very weird error that I don't understand. Also, when I go back to the screen from where I started(the one that sends location), I get the same error and it keeps popping up on the terminal every 5 seconds instead of the location. The sending location part is basically an API where I post the latitude and longitude. Here is the error:

```
E/flutter (12094): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
E/flutter (12094): Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
```

Following are the codes for the location sending and navigation bar widgets:

Widget that sends the location. Also, clicking on the button toggles the value of the `status` variable between `active` and `inactive`. This changes the color of the button and also puts an end to the api call that sends the location:

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isLoading = true;
  bool isPressed = false;
  String? status;

  Future<void> getStatus() async {     //This method stores the status in localStorage
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    status = localStorage.getString('loginStatus');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    // statusExec();
    Provider.of<ChangeLocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .getLocationDetails()
        .then((_) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });

    getStatus();

    status == 'active' ? isPressed = true : isPressed = false;     //This here determines the status from the localStorage when we come back from another screen

    super.initState();
  }

  apiCall(String execStatus) async {     //This is the method that sends the location
    print('Is Pressed: $isPressed');
    print('execStatus: $execStatus');
    Random number = Random();

    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) {
      if (isPressed == true) {
        double latitude = Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false)    
            .coorDinates['lat'];             //The error points at this line
        // double latitude = number.nextDouble();
        double longitude = Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .coorDinates['lng'];
        // double longitude = number.nextDouble();
        print('Latitude LAt: $latitude');
        print('Longitude Long: $longitude');
        print('Status Inside: $status');
        Provider.of<ChangeLocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .postLocation(latitude, longitude, execStatus);
      } else {
        double latitude = Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .coorDinates['lat'];
        // double latitude = number.nextDouble();
        double longitude = Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .coorDinates['lng'];
        Provider.of<ChangeLocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .postLocation(latitude, longitude, execStatus);
        t.cancel();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final tabLayout = width > 600;
    final largeLayout = width > 350 && width < 600;
    final provider =
        Provider.of<ChangeLocationProvider>(context).locationDetails;

    print('Address ${Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context).address}');

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(
                  'assets/images/WhatsApp Image 2022-04-12 at 13.21.05.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: height * 0.05),
                  child: Text(
                    'Get Set Go',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: !tabLayout && !largeLayout ? 25 : 35),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: width * 0.25,
            top: !tabLayout && !largeLayout ? height * 0.42 : height * 0.4,
            right: width * 0.25,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                SharedPreferences localStorage =
                    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                  setState(() {
                    isPressed = !isPressed;
                    status = isPressed == true ? 'active' : 'inactive';
                    localStorage.setString('loginStatus', status!);
                    print(isPressed);
                    print(status);
                  });
                if (status == 'active') {
                  apiCall(status!);
                } else {
                  return;
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                width: width * 0.05,
                height: height * 0.15,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          offset: Offset(1, 2))
                    ]),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: width * 0.02,
                    height: height * 0.15,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: status == 'active'
                          ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 36, 192, 41)
                          : Colors.red,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        status == 'active' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            .............
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

}

Bottom Navigation Bar widget:

```
class CustomBottomNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isPressed;

  CustomBottomNavigationState createState() => CustomBottomNavigationState();

  CustomBottomNavigation(this.isPressed);
}

class CustomBottomNavigationState extends State<CustomBottomNavigation> {
  int index = 0;
  bool isLoading = true;
  String? status;
  bool? isButtonPressed;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    Provider.of<ProfileProvider>(context, listen: false).getProfile().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
    // print('IS PRESSSSSSSED: ${widget.isPressed}');
    super.initState();
  }

  final screens = [
    HomePage(),      //This is the initial page and also where the API gets called
    Dashboard(),
    // Notifications(),
    Profile(),
    PresentOrders(),
    DeliveredOrders()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final profileProvider = Provider.of<ProfileProvider>(context).profile;

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        body: isLoading
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              )
            : screens[index],
        extendBody: true,
        bottomNavigationBar: isLoading
            ? const Text('....')
            : Container(
                height: height * 0.06,
                width: double.infinity,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: height * 0.02),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Container(
                        width: width * 0.75,
                        height: height * 0.05,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  blurRadius: 5,
                                  offset: Offset(0, 2))
                            ]),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: double.infinity,
                              width: width * 0.35,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.02),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        index = 3;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                        'assets/images/Icon awesome-shopping-cart.png'),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: width * 0.1),
                                  InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        index = 1;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                        'assets/images/Icon ionic-ios-settings.png'),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: double.infinity,
                              width: width * 0.35,
                              // padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: width * 0.02),
                              // color: Colors.blue,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.06),
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          index = 4;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Icon(Icons.delivery_dining_rounded,
                                          size: 35),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: width * 0.1),
                                  InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          index = 2;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: profileProvider['data']
                                                  ['profile_pic'] ==
                                              null
                                          ? const CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 15,
                                              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                                            )
                                          : CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 15,
                                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                                  'http://34.100.212.22${profileProvider['data']['profile_pic']}'),
                                              // child: ClipRRect(
                                              //     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                              //     child: Image.network(
                                              //       'http://34.100.212.22${profileProvider['data']['profile_pic']}',
                                              //       fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                              //     )),
                                            ))
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home-screen');
            setState(() {
              index = 0;
            });
          },
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              // height: height * 0.075,
              // width: width * 0.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  boxShadow: const [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey, blurRadius: 5, offset: Offset(0, 2))
                  ],
                  border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.green, width: 2, style: BorderStyle.solid)),
              child: Center(
                // child: Image.asset('assets/images/Icon ionic-ios-home.png')
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable of type timer:

```dart
late Timer _timer;
```

Assign the timer that you defined to this variable:

```
_timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
   // Implementation of apis you already added
 }
);
```

Now in the dispose method cancel this timer:

```dart
@override
void dispose(){
  _timer.cancel();//cancel the timer here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your timer callback which captures the state's context in `Provider.of<XXX>(context, listen: false)` (6 such calls in the timer function).

Cancelling the timer as Kaushik Chandru recommends will make sure this code is not called anymore when the state is dismissed. But it will also stop the timer while the user is browsing away from this screen. So if you want the timer to run as some sort of background service to your app, you'll need another solution.

For instance, you could get hold of the providers in the click handler and pass them to your apiCall function, eg:

```dart
apiCall(LocationProvider locationProvider, ChangeLocationProvider changeLocationProvider, String execStatus) async {
    print('Is Pressed: $isPressed');
    print('execStatus: $execStatus');

    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) {
      if (isPressed == true) {
        double latitude = locationProvider.coorDinates['lat'];
        double longitude = locationProvider.coorDinates['lng'];
        changeLocationProvider.postLocation(latitude, longitude, execStatus);
      } else {
        double latitude = locationProvider.coorDinates['lat'];
        double longitude = locationProvider.coorDinates['lng'];
        changeLocationProvider.postLocation(latitude, longitude, execStatus);
        t.cancel();
      }
    });
  }
```

And the click handler becomes:

```dart
onTap: () async {
  SharedPreferences localStorage =
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   setState(() {
     isPressed = !isPressed;
     status = isPressed == true ? 'active' : 'inactive';
     localStorage.setString('loginStatus', status!);
     print(isPressed);
     print(status);
   });
   if (status == 'active') {
     apiCall(
       Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false),
       Provider.of<ChangeLocationProvider>(context, listen: false),
       status!,
     );
   } else {
     return;
   }
 },
```

But there's another problem in your code, because the timer function also captures the state's `isPressed` field. If the state is disposed while `isPressed` is `true`, the timer will run forever because when the user comes back to the screen, a new instance (with a different `isPressed` field) will be created. So you might end up with two timers running.

I believe you should decouple the code between the UI and the timer's callback. The periodic service should have its own class, typically a Singleton, and should manage the state (active/inactive) by itself. The UI code should only use the class to start/stop the service.